# How to resolve virtual disk degraded in Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, degraded, storage-spaces

I am using the new Storage Spaces feature in Windows Server 2012. I have the following disks:

```
FriendlyName        CanPool             OperationalStatus   HealthStatus        Usage                              Size
------------        -------             -----------------   ------------        -----                              ----
PhysicalDisk2       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     2.73 TB
PhysicalDisk3       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     2.73 TB
PhysicalDisk4       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     2.73 TB
PhysicalDisk5       False               OK                  Healthy             Auto-Select                     2.73 TB
```

There is also a separate OS disk. The above disks are part of a single storage pool:

```
FriendlyName            OperationalStatus       HealthStatus            IsPrimordial            IsReadOnly
------------            -----------------       ------------            ------------            ----------
Pool                    OK                      Healthy                 False                   False
```

Within this storage pool some virtual disks are defined, see below:

```
FriendlyName        ResiliencySettingNa OperationalStatus   HealthStatus        IsManualAttach                     Size
                    me
------------        ------------------- -----------------   ------------        --------------                     ----
Docs                Mirror              OK                  Healthy             False                            500 GB
Data                Mirror              Degraded            Warning             False                            500 GB
Work                Mirror              Degraded            Warning             False                              2 TB
```

Now the virtual disks are all running normal 2-way mirror, but two of the virtual disks are degraded. This is probably because one of the physical disks was offline for a short period of time. However, now the virtual disk cannot be repaired, even though, all physical disks are healthy. There is plenty of available space in the storage pool.

This I cannot understand so I was hoping for some help, on how to resolve this?

Below I have listed the full output from the Get-VirtualDisk CmdLet for the "Work" disk:

```
ObjectId                          : {XXXXXXXX}
PassThroughClass                  :
PassThroughIds                    :
PassThroughNamespace              :
PassThroughServer                 :
UniqueId                          : XXXXXXXX
Access                            : Read/Write
AllocatedSize                     : 412316860416
DetachedReason                    : None
FootprintOnPool                   : 824633720832
FriendlyName                      : Work
HealthStatus                      : Warning
Interleave                        : 262144
IsDeduplicationEnabled            : False
IsEnclosureAware                  : False
IsManualAttach                    : False
IsSnapshot                        : False
LogicalSectorSize                 : 512
Name                              :
NameFormat                        :
NumberOfAvailableCopies           : 0
NumberOfColumns                   : 2
NumberOfDataCopies                : 2
OperationalStatus                 : Degraded
OtherOperationalStatusDescription :
OtherUsageDescription             : Disk for data being worked on (not backed up)
ParityLayout                      :
PhysicalDiskRedundancy            : 1
PhysicalSectorSize                : 4096
ProvisioningType                  : Thin
RequestNoSinglePointOfFailure     : True
ResiliencySettingName             : Mirror
Size                              : 2199023255552
UniqueIdFormat                    : Vendor Specific
UniqueIdFormatDescription         :
Usage                             : Other
PSComputerName                    :
```

Comment: I believe you may have hit some bug, actually Microsoft itself advertises it as "Experimental" features (can't find the MSDN article anymore grrr), anyway contacting Microsoft about that might give you a better response (I hope they are willing to investigate this issue)...

Comment: How long has it been since the disk was offline? Could it possibly be 're-building' the data onto the previously failed disks?

Answer (score 2):

I would try this KB article from Microsoft. Sounds similar to the issue you described.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2885668

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `repair-volume`? Source: http://www.petri.co.il/disk-repair-powershell-cmdlets-windows-server-2012.htm

Comment: yes this does nothing

Comment: i.e. NoErrorsFound

Answer (score 0):

After making a backup of one of Virtual Disks, remove the mirrors and add it back again.

Also can see how much space is available on the actual drives.

Comment: I see that this will probably solve the issue, e.g. starting from scratch will solve it, but it is not really the answer I am looking for. This should be something handled by storage spaces in a transparent and reliable way...

Comment: That should be transparent. Removing and readding the mirrow will recreate a valid copy of the data. THe backup is standard security procedure.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a process called Soft Disk Replacement. For that you should have a hot spare. The idea is to swap one of the disks with a hot spare and start repair-virtual disk.

If you have multiple enclosures, make sure you swap with a right hot spare. A virtual disk should have two disks from two different enclosures for high availability.